How to create two details section with headers separated under group header section?
I work on crystal report I face issue how to display two details section with different headers related to same group by licenserecid ?
I can display first section related to group licenserecid  without any issue
but how to display second section with different header group by licenserecid this is exactly my question
so exactly I need to display data related to multi details on same group
example
I make group  header add group by licenserecid 415384
I display first header related to count employee data
Name    count   amount
ahmed   5          200
salem    8          300

until here no issue
I get new modification to get data related to licenserecid 415384 that have reservations
so I will make another details with different header
here is my issue how to create new details related to group by licenserecid 415384
with different header
Name      Date            count      ReservationNo
michel   01/01/2024        0              200321
tony     14/04/2024        0              3002111

Full structure order from top to bottom to report
group header
Header A
DetailsA
Header B
DetailsB
How to add details be with header under first section
Expected output as
image for expected 
what I try on crystal report
Last update
I need small bit help I'm near from reach my result
what I do insert sub report on group footer A
sub report include header b and details b
what after that I will do can you clarify please
AND what is goal or benfit from make sub report link

Crystal Reports allows you to insert a linked subreport in any section.
You can insert a subreport in GF1 (Footer A using your terminology). In that subreport, display your Header B and Detals B info. And filter the subreport to the current licenserecid by passing it as a subreport link.
Crystal's Help includes a chapter on Subreports and a section on Linking a subreport to the data in the primary repor.

thanks for support can you clarify more details
i make on details a subreport owners and on details b subreport creditors are this is correct

Sorry, it is difficult to understand what you are asking.
I suggest you first read the HELP sections I mentioned above.
Perhaps also watch some YouTube videos on how to create subreports (simply search for Crystal Reports Subreports). Once you understand how linked subreports work, you'll know how to proceed.
